# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames

Tags: python, csv

Can someone help me with this.

I have my Select query

```
selectAttendance = """SELECT * FROM table """
```

And I want the content of my select query and include a header when I download the csv file,
So I did this query:

```
with open(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'csv.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames  = ["Bio_Id","Last_Name","First_Name","late","undertime","total_minutes", "total_ot", "total_nsd", "total_absences"], delimiter = ';')
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow(db.session.execute(selectAttendance))
            db.session.commit()
```

but it gives me this error

```
**ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames**
```

I want to have like this output in my downloaded csv file:

```
Bio_Id Last_Name First_Name late undertime total_minutes total_ot total_nsd total_absences
1      Joe       Spark       1     1            2            1        1          1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So have you looked at the dictionary and compared it to the headers you specify?

Comment: What's unclear in the error message?

Comment: I don't know why after ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames:***content of the select*** not saving in the specified csv

Comment: Because after the error *nothing happens*; the program has crashed.

Comment: @BartoszKP Im here cuz I dont understand the error msg, can you explain it?

Comment: My problem was that I had taken out a dictionary key/value in the first dictionary in an array of dictionaries and I was passing `arr[0].keys()` to `fieldnames` but `arr[1:]` all still had the extra field, hence the error

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the error states: the dictionary that comes from the query contains more key than the field names you specified in the DictWriter constructor.

One solution would be to filter that in advance, something like this:

```
field_names = ["Bio_Id","Last_Name", ...]
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=field_names , delimiter = ';')
writer.writeheader()
data = {key: value for key, value in db.session.execute(selectAttendance).items()
        if key in field_names}
writer.writerow(data)
```

Another solution could be to construct the query using only those fields:

```
query = 'SELECT %s FROM table' % ', '.join(field_names)
```

However, Tim Pietzcker's answer is the best.

Answer (score 202):

As the error message clearly states, your dictionary contains keys that don't have a corresponding entry in your `fieldnames` parameter. Assuming that these are just extra fields, you can ignore them [by using the `extrasaction` parameter during construction of your `DictWriter` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["Bio_Id","Last_Name","First_Name","late","undertime","total_minutes", "total_ot", "total_nsd", "total_absences"], 
                        extrasaction='ignore', delimiter = ';')
```

Answer (score 1):

To bring up to date the [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) now has an option `extrasaction='ignore'` parameter.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```py
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['a','b','c'], extrasaction='ignore')
csv_writer.writerow({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a possible solution for the dumbass cut'n paste programmer squad (of which I am a charter member!)

If you define your titles like this:

```
customerTitles = '"ID","Gender","Type","Full Name","Territory","Customer Group","Tax ID","Customer Details"'
```

You will definitely see the `Value Error` the OP encountered.

However, using the `extrasaction='ignore'` flag and checking the resultant file you will see this beauty:

```
"""",I,D,"""",",","""",G,e,n,d,e,r,"""",",","""",T,y,p,e,"""",",","""",F,u,l,l, ,N,a,m,e,"""",",","""",T,e,r,r,i,t,o,r,y,"""",",","""",C,u,s,t,o,m,e,r, ,G,r,o,u,p,"""",",","""",T,a,x, ,I,D,"""",",","""",C,u,s,t,o,m,e,r, ,D,e,t,a,i,l,s,""""
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi all thank you for answering. 
I finally found out how to make it. 
here is the code

```
    w = csv.writer(file(r'test.csv','wb'), delimiter=';')
    w.writerows([["Bio Id","Last Name",.....]])
    w.writerows(db.session.execute(selectAttendance))
    db.session.commit()
```