# Code fails to run when there is no data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, elasticsearch

When I run my below query and there is no data in the values such as `["VT","NCR","N","DT","RD"],`  the query fails.

With the error message of

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: ‘VT’
```

Is there a way to say if there is no data in any of the values still carry on running the query to grab data for the values that have data in python?
For example: the ‘TRY’, ‘CATCH’, or ’PASS’ method?

I have been struggling on this for days, could someone show me how to do this?

My Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])


res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["VT","NCR","N","DT","RD"],
                    "query": {

                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{"range": {"VT": {
                                            "gte": "now/d",
                                            "lte": "now+1d/d"}}},

                                {"wildcard": {"user": "mike*"}}]}}},size=10)


csv_file = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'


header_names = { 'VT': 'Date', 'NCR': 'ExTime', 'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period'}



with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names,) 
            header_present = True
             w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: Look up `dict.get()`

Comment: you able to show me how to use this with my code?

Comment: Where's that error? Show the full traceback please

Comment: You never assigned a variable named `VT` or `DT` here. Or you're missing some code

Comment: @ cricket - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rich/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/TRY.py", line 57, in <module>
    w.writerow(header_names,)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
  File "C:\Users\Rich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Rich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 151, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'VT'

Comment: oh you able to show me what i am missing if you dont mind? its been stressing me out

Comment: Please [edit] your question... I'm saying your quotes are off `header_names = { VT: Date', NCR`

Comment: @ cricket, i just saw that and updated my code. you got a idea on what is missing?

Comment: @cricket, do you know what i am trying to do here? if there is data in VT or not it should still create the CSV and grab the data for the other variables

Comment: Unrelated, but do you need CSV? Or can you write JSON, since that's what you're getting anyway? The error exists in the CSV writer, which would work fine even with missing values, but `w.writerow(my_dict)` definitely needs indented

Comment: do you understand what my post is for? i think you are mistaking what i have asked for. When there is no data for VT the query fails to run and does not create the CSV or carries on grabbing the data for the rest of the headers.

Comment: Seen this? Search that error message otherwise?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944505/2308683

Comment: would you know how i can use that and put that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out a flaw in your comment

```
 # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
 w.writerow(header_names,)
```

Actually, it writes out the values of the the dictionary under the headers of the keys... Therefore you're writing two headers, basically.

Regarding the error, [according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) , you can ignore missing fields and set default values when they don't exist

> The optional `restval` parameter specifies the value to be written if the dictionary is missing a key in `fieldnames`. If the dictionary passed to the writerow() method contains a key not found in fieldnames, the optional `extrasaction` parameter indicates what action to take. If it is set to 'raise', the default value, a ValueError is raised. If it is set to 'ignore', extra values in the dictionary are ignored.

For example

```
with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    # Open one csv for all the results 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header_names.keys(), restval='', extrasaction='ignore') 
    # There's only one header, don't need a boolean flag 
    w.writeheader()  
    # proceed to write results 
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']
        # Parse this dictionary however you need to write a valid CSV row 
        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Otherwise, don't use a DictWriter and form the CSV row yourself. You can use `dict.get()` to extract values, but set default values that don't exist in the data

Comment: you able to show me how? honestly im struggling on it

Comment: How to do what exactly? I've given two options here... I might suggest stepping back, generating fake data, and learn the ins and outs of DictWriter, and determine if you really need it. I will point out that `w.writerow(header_names,)` looks unnecessary unless you do want "double" headers

Comment: from your suggestions it sounds like dict.get() will be good to use because you said 'You can use dict.get() to extract values, but set default values that don't exist in the data' but i am not sure how to use dict.get(). unless you are willing to show me how to use it with my above code

Comment: i just tried your code above and i am getting a error on fieldnames=my_dict.keys

Comment: I'm sure you can find plenty of examples elsewhere, but for example `vt = my_dict.get('VT', 'default VT')`

Comment: your updated version works however i am having the issue where it is bringing back data for everything not just the data for {"wildcard": {"user": "mike*"}}

Comment: are you able to help me figure out  with your updated code on how to only bring back the data for the wildcard above as this was working before your suggestion code

Comment: Sorry, not good with Elasticsearch queries. All I changed was the ordering of your code. The hit results should still exist

Comment: no worries, thank you for taking a look! appreciate it

Comment: Welcome . By the way, you might want to try a prefix query rather than wildcard