# Exporting response.txt to csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse data that I receive from a curl request through python. The data is in the following format:

```
{'meta': {'from': '1520812800',
          'granularity': 'daily',
          'to': '1523232000',
          'total': 6380},
 'data': [{'count': 660, 'date': '2018-03-12'},
          {'count': 894, 'date': '2018-03-13'}]}
```

Originally, the data was returned as a string probably because I used response.text to retrieve the data. I converted the string into a dictionary using `ast.literal_eval(response.text)`. I managed to parse the `"data"` key and ignore `"meta"`. So currently,

```
data = [{"date":"2018-03-12","count":660},{"date":"2018-03-13","count":894}]}`.
```

I am trying to export the values for "date" and "count" to a csv file. In my code I have this:

```
keys = data[0].keys()
print("----------KEYS:---------")
print keys #['date','count']
print("------------------------")

with open('mycsv.csv','wb') as output_file:
  thewriter = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames =
  ['date','count'])

  thewriter.writeheader()
  thewriter.writerow(data)
```

However, python does not like this and gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curlparser.py", line 45, in <module>
    thewriter.writerow(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: {"date":"2018-03-12","count":660},{"date":"2018-03-13","count":894}
```

Comment: `writerow` expects to be diven a single dictionary which is the data for one row. You are passing it the list of all rows. Change it to `for row in data: thewriter.writerow(row)` and you'll prob get a bit further.

Comment: This link should help a little
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944274/valueerror-dict-contains-fields-not-in-fieldnames

Comment: Try using `thewriter.writerows()` instead of `thewriter.writerow()`. Note the `s` added to the end.