# dict contains fields not in fieldnames: Cannot write data into CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I am trying to write append the data of list in CSV file. Here is my code:

```
body = {
        'dont-ask-for-email': 0,
        'action': 'submit_user_review',
        'post_id': 76196,
        'email': email_random(),
        'subscribe': 1,
        'previous_hosting_id': prev_hosting_comp_random(),
        'fb_token': '',
        'title': review_title_random(),
        'summary': summary_random(),
        'score_pricing': star_random(),
        'score_userfriendly': star_random(),
        'score_support': star_random(),
        'score_features': star_random(),
        'hosting_type': hosting_type_random(),
        'author': name_random(),
        'social_link': '',
        'site': '',
        'screenshot[image][]': '',
        'screenshot[description][]': '',
        'user_data_process_agreement': 1,
        'user_email_popup': '',
        'subscribe_popup': 1,
        'email_asked': 1
}
from csv import DictWriter
fields = ['DontAskForEmail','Action','PostID','Email','Subsribe','PreviousHostingID','FbToken','Title','Summary','Pricing','UserFriend']
def datasent(r3eData, body, fields):
        with open(r3eData, 'a+', newline='') as writeData:
                dict_writer = DictWriter(writeData, fieldnames = fields)
                dict_writer.writerow(body)
datasent('r3edata.csv', body, fields)
```

When I run this, I get this error `dict contains fields not in fieldnames:`
Here is the traceback:

```
[root@b00gi3m4n boogieman]# python codeOffshoreupdated.py 
https://www.facebook.com/AedanKerr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 120, in <module>
    datasent('r3edata.csv', body, fields)
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 119, in datasent
    dict_writer.writerow(body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/csv.py", line 151, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'screenshot[description][]', 'email_asked', 'action', 'title', 'score_support', 'social_link', 'email', 'score_features', 'summary', 'score_pricing', 'author', 'previous_hosting_id', 'dont-ask-for-email', 'post_id', 'site', 'user_data_process_agreement', 'subscribe', 'fb_token', 'subscribe_popup', 'screenshot[image][]', 'hosting_type', 'score_userfriendly', 'user_email_popup'
```

How do I fix this?

Also, I have another question. 
*I would like to update this list every 10 minutes, and I do not want to lose any previous data on every update. Is this method going to update the list every time or will it override the previous data and update the new list ?*

*If it will override the data, how do I update the new data into a new row?*
(Pardon my English please,I can explain more in the comments if you do not get it)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could refer this answer to solve your error:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944519/6618812

Comment: Okay, I will. Can you answer my question too?

Comment: The answer seems right in front of you. `body` dict has, e.g. a `dont-ask-for-email` key, but you have a `DontAskForEmail` field in your query. Make sure those are equal strings (i.e. pass `dont-ask-for-email` in your `fields` instead). Same for every other key with conflicting field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the length of your `fields`, but for some reason I couldn't get there using DictWrite. So another way to approach it is to load the whole thing to a pandas dataframe and write that to a csv file:

```
columns = []
rows = []
chunks = body.split('}')
for chunk in chunks:  
    row = []
    if len(chunk)>1:        
        entry = chunk.replace('{','').strip().split(',')
        for e in entry:
            item = e.strip().split(':')
            if len(item)==2:
                row.append(item[1])
                if chunks.index(chunk)==0:
                    columns.append(item[0])
        rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = columns)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    'dont-ask-for-email'    'action'    'post_id'   'email'     'subscribe'     'previous_hosting_id'   'fb_token'  'title'     'summary'   'score_pricing'     ...     'hosting_type'  'author'    'social_link'   'site'  'screenshot[image][]'   'screenshot[description][]'     'user_data_process_agreement'   'user_email_popup'  'subscribe_popup'   'email_asked'
0   0   'submit_user_review'    76196   email_random()  1   prev_hosting_comp_random()  ''  review_title_random()   summary_random()    star_random()   ...     hosting_type_random()   some_name_random()  ''  ''  ''  ''  1   ''  4   2 }
```

And then to save to csv use:

```
df.to_csv ('r3edata.csv', index = False, header=True)
```