# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'ï»¿timestamp'

Tags: python

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    with open('new_file.csv','w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['timestamp','src-user','dst-user']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

I wrote this code to create new csv file from old one with appending to it 
 when i tried to write it as dictionary it shows me this error **ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'ï»¿timestamp'**

Comment: It is probably because the names of the columns in csv do not match to the fieldbames that you have provided. Can you add the first line of csv to the answer?

Comment: Also this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944274/valueerror-dict-contains-fields-not-in-fieldnames

Comment: It looks like there might be some corruption or garbage at the beginning of your csv file as well, since the field still has timestamp eventually

Comment: Try this, [replace non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Comment: It's not corruption; it's a byte-order mark encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @RajKumar  can you give me your email to contact you please